# Inline Payment Icons

Tags: html, css, shopify

I'm using SVG payment icons in the footer of my website. However, I want to inline them. I tried playing with the CSS but still nothing is happening. Currently, the icons are displayed as a list. How can I inline them?

Here's the Footer code:

```html
<footer class="page-footer variant4 fullboxed">
    <div class="footer-bot">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="footer-nav">
            <ul>
                {% for link in linklists[settings.footer_nav]links %}
                    <li>{{ link.title | link_to: link.url }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
          </div>
      {% unless shop.enabled_payment_types == empty %}
      {% assign payment_icons_available = 'amazon_payments,american_express,apple_pay,bitcoin,cirrus,dankort,diners_club,discover,dogecoin,dwolla,forbrugsforeningen,interac,jcb,litecoin,maestro,master,paypal,visa' | split: ',' %}
        <div class="payment-icons">
          {% for type in shop.enabled_payment_types %}
            {% if payment_icons_available contains type %}
              {% assign icon_name = type | prepend: 'icon-' %}
                {% include icon_name %}
                {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
      </div>
    {% endunless %}
  </div>
</footer>
```

And here's the CSS:

```css
.payment-icons {

  width: 50px;
  margin: auto; !important;

}
```

Comment: Note that snippets should be used for runnable code; when I click on Run code snippet, not much happens. Also, it would be easier to reproduce your issue if you provided the rendered HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're currently relying on the container of the SVG elements to control the width (50px) of each SVG, which makes it impossible for each SVG to flow next to each other. Adjust your CSS so that the container, `div.payment-icons`, can be 100% of the outer container and adjust each SVG element to specifically 50px width. From here, you can add additional CSS to space the SVG icons across the page:

```
svg:not(:root) {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
}

.payment-icons {
    width: auto;
    margin: auto;
}
```

In order to perfectly space out your SVG icons, adjust your footer HTML so that each SVG icon has a list-item container:

```
<div class="payment-icons">
    <ul>
      {% for type in shop.enabled_payment_types %}
        {% if payment_icons_available contains type %}
        <li>
            {% assign icon_name = type | prepend: 'icon-' %}
                {% include icon_name %}
            {% endif %}
        </li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

Then include the following CSS:

```
svg:not(:root) {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.payment-icons {
     // nothing should be needed here, unless you want negative margins to have the left-most and right-most icons to be against the "wall" of the container
}
.payment-icons ul {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.payment-icons ul li {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**Update, mobile**:

```
@media (min-width: 300px) {
    svg:not(:root) {
        overflow: hidden;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .payment-icons {
        width: auto;
        margin: auto;
    }
    .payment-icons ul {
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .payment-icons ul li {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        padding: 0 5px;
    }
}

// tablet+
@media (min-width: 767px) {
    svg:not(:root) {
        width: 50px;
    }

    .payment-icons ul {
        width: 25%;
    }
    .payment-icons ul li {
        padding: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi there i tried your first answer. It inlined the icons however they were not perfectly inlined.

I tried updating the footer code as listed in your second answer. They got back displaying as a list. You can check it out at the website.

Comment: Once you update the html, add the CSS that I included below that update.

Comment: I did, notice that they are not perfectly inlined. And they are not centered.

Here's how they should look like: http://imgur.com/VBjWbZg

Comment: do you want the icons to span across the whole page? and are you trying to accomplish the same design for mobile? For vertical alignment, I just added "vertical-align: middle" to the li css selector.

Comment: I added vertical-align: middle; It's now perfectly inlined. However, when resizing the width from 100% to 35%, it's going back to the left side of the footer.

Comment: updated for desktop, so you can now set the width to 35%. For mobile, are you using mobile first approach?

Comment: This theme i'm using is not made by me. So i'm not sure about that.

Comment: @Ned updated to include media queries so that you can adjust mobile (be careful, cascades up into tablet because of mobile first approach). If this is resolved, go ahead and mark as answer.

Comment: I actually don't know how to thank you. Your answer is what i was looking for.

Comment: However, i still have one more problem left. The CSS you gave me is actually affecting every svg icons of my website. The logo for example, how can i exclude the logo from it?

Comment: Instead of just the svg selector, append the ".payment-icons" before it: `.payment-icons svg { ... style properties here.. }`, since payment-icons is a parent of those SVG's

Comment: ^This is beginner level css. I highly recommend taking 30 minutes to learn from a tutorial site.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
.payment-icons 
   width: 100%;


.icon 
    display: inline;
    width: 10%;
    vertical-align: middle;
```

I tested it on your website in the inspector and it worked.